# Edit jqgrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

as i am new to jqgrid,my question be stupid one, my requirement is that i need to implement an editable jqgrid.but the problem is i want one column to be in editable form by default.

```
{ name: 'Description', index: 'Description', classes: 'align_left padding_left_10 padding_right_10', width: '290', editable: true },
```

i have set editable option to true.i can achieve requirement by using

```
 var grid = $jqGrid("#" + gridid + ""),
                          ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i, l = ids.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    grid.jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
                }
```

but this makes other columns also to editable form.is there any way to achieve single column editable mode by default.Thanks in advance.

Comment: which columns have `editable: true` property? only the columns will be editable. How you fill the data in the grid? Which `datatype` you use? In the most scenarios calling of ` editRow` for all rows of the grid is not good.

Comment: sorry for the wrong formation of question, i need to have editable column in open (textbox) form in gridcomplete event.i am using json with loadonce true.